# How to build a subset of nodes in workspace?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm developing a multi-computer ROS project where each processor has multiple nodes running on it. We've found that builds have become quite long as we're not cross compiling yet and so some of the smaller embedded processors can take a decent amount of time to build the whole workspace despite not needing to build every package.

I've been looking into a way to specify a single target which can be specified like `catkin_make --pkg <target>` such that all of the packages required for a node on a specific end target are built. I thought metapackages might be the answer for this, but they seem to address a different problem.

Is there a standard way to equate a catkin target to a set of packages so that the whole codebase does not need to be built? I see this as also being useful for cross compiling anyway for having a single target to cross compile.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317799/how-to-build-a-subset-of-nodes-in-workspace?/) by [ssnover](https://answers.ros.org/users/39852/ssnover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I've been looking into a way to specify a single target which can be specified like `catkin_make --pkg <target>` such that all of the packages required for a node on a specific end target are built.

`catkin_make` should allow you to do that, if you use the `--only-pkg-with-deps` option:

```
  --only-pkg-with-deps ONLY_PKG_WITH_DEPS [ONLY_PKG_WITH_DEPS ...]
                        Whitelist only the specified packages and their
                        dependencies by setting the CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES
                        variable. This variable is stored in CMakeCache.txt
                        and will persist between CMake calls unless explicitly
                        cleared; e.g. catkin_make
                        -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="".
```

Alternatively, [catkin_tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) supports profiles, that in turn can be configured with specific [white and blacklists](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#whitelisting-and-blacklisting-packages) of packages.

In addition you can ask it to build just a single package with all it's dependencies:

```
catkin build <pkg_name>
```

or even just a package without its dependencies:

```
catkin build <pkg_name> --no-deps
```

See [catkin build – Build Packages](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html) for the documentation of the `build` verb and the [Building Subsets of Packages](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html#building-subsets-of-packages) section.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1